# Is using Controller::render() in a Model::afterSave() possible with CakePHP?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, cakephp

I've got some sample code that I'd like to refactor as I need it to work after a record is saved. It currently works after the record is first rendered (using the afterFilter). What it does is render the view that I want with the layout and saves it to a file.

```
function afterFilter() {
    parent::afterFilter();
    if($this->params['pass'][0] == 'contact') {
        $surrenderOuput = $this->surrender($this->params['pass'][0]);
        $path = WWW_ROOT . 'cache' . DS . $this->params['pass'][0] . DS . 'index.html';
        $file = new File($path, true);
        $file->write($surrenderOuput);
        $file->close();
    }
}
function surrender($action = null, $layout = null, $file = null) {
    $this->beforeRender();

    $viewClass = $this->view;
    if ($this->view != 'View') {
        if (strpos($viewClass, '.') !== false) {
            list($plugin, $viewClass) = explode('.', $viewClass);
        }
        $viewClass = $viewClass . 'View';
        App::import('View', $this->view);
    }

    $this->Component->beforeRender($this);

    $this->params['models'] = $this->modelNames;

    if (Configure::read() > 2) {
        $this->set('cakeDebug', $this);
    }

    $View =& new $viewClass($this);

    if (!empty($this->modelNames)) {
        $models = array();
        foreach ($this->modelNames as $currentModel) {
            if (isset($this->$currentModel) && is_a($this->$currentModel, 'Model')) {
                $models[] = Inflector::underscore($currentModel);
            }
            $isValidModel = (
                isset($this->$currentModel) && is_a($this->$currentModel, 'Model') &&
                !empty($this->$currentModel->validationErrors)
            );
            if ($isValidModel) {
                $View->validationErrors[Inflector::camelize($currentModel)] =&
                    $this->$currentModel->validationErrors;
            }
        }
        $models = array_diff(ClassRegistry::keys(), $models);
        foreach ($models as $currentModel) {
            if (ClassRegistry::isKeySet($currentModel)) {
                $currentObject =& ClassRegistry::getObject($currentModel);
                if (is_a($currentObject, 'Model') && !empty($currentObject->validationErrors)) {
                    $View->validationErrors[Inflector::camelize($currentModel)] =&
                        $currentObject->validationErrors;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $this->autoRender = false;
    $output = $View->render($action, $layout, $file);

    return $output;
}
```

So I'm basically rendering the view with it's layout, and returning it as output, and saving it to a file. Great. Is there any way to do something similar in a model?

Comment: I'm sure there is some way of hacking it together, but that would be in gross violation of the MVC structure and would almost certainly have side effects. Why do you want to render a certain view every time you save a record?

Comment: In order to cache that view as a file. The host (Godaddy) has terrible performance as far as mysql is concerned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider setting a member variable in your afterSave() in the model and checking that value in your afterFilter() in your controller.

Comment: I ended up doing a behavior using the Model::afterSave(). Took a while to figure out how to do so, but using Controller::render() is not the way. Controller::requestAction(), and passing in a param that either auto-renders the layout checked in the beforeFilter, seemed to solve my problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread while searching for how to render a view from a model. In my case I'm calling a custom method in the model, so this might not work for afterSave(), but if you're calling a custom method you can do it like this:

Controller:

```
$this->Model->myFunc($this);
```

Model

```
public function myFunc($object) {
 $object->render();
}
```

Hopefully that helps someone else who comes across this thread.